# How to convert Nested array object to a flat table angularjs dynamically using recursive function?

Tags: javascript

Here is the Nested array Object example. How to recursively append parent elements to the child elements of table?

Please note: there can be n number of levels in nested objects

```
var data = {
  "grandparent_id": 7,
"parents": [
  {
      "parent_id": 65,
          "children": [
          {
          "child_id": 365
          }
          ]
  },
  {
      "parent_id": 66,
          "children": [
          {
          "child_id": 365
          },
          {
          "child_id": 366
          },
          {
          "child_id": 367,   
                  "smallchildren": [
              {
              "smallchild_id": 465
              },
              {
              "smallchild_id": 466
              },
              {
              "smallchild_id": 467
              }
              ]
  }    
  ]
  }
]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
var resultArray = [[7,65,365],[7,66,365],[7,66,366],[7,66,367]]
```

---

```
Grandparent_id|parent_id|child_id
7             |65       |365
7             |66       |365
7             |66       |366   
7             |66       |367
```

---

Tried this:

```
 function normalize(parent) {
    if (parent && parent.children) {
        for (var i = 0, l = parent.children.length; i < l; ++i) {
            var child = parent.children[i];
            child.index = i;
            if (!child.parentId) child.parentId = parent.id || '0';
            normalize(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your input and expected output as JavaScript Object/Array literals? that will help people help you.

Comment: updated with expected input and output.

Comment: clean up complete

Comment: yes, it was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a pretty simple map/reduce job. Simply iterate the `parents` array and map the `children` array into an array of `data.grandparent_id`, `parent.parent_id` and `child.child_id`.

```js
const data = {"grandparent_id":7,"parents":[{"parent_id":65,"children":[{"child_id":365}]},{"parent_id":66,"children":[{"child_id":365},{"child_id":366},{"child_id":367}]}]}

const resultArray = data.parents.reduce((arr, parent) => {
  return arr.concat(parent.children.map(child =>
    [data.grandparent_id, parent.parent_id, child.child_id]))
}, [])

console.info('resultArray =', JSON.stringify(resultArray))
```

---

If you want the inner arrays to be objects instead, simply change the `map` return value...

```js
const data = {"grandparent_id":7,"parents":[{"parent_id":65,"children":[{"child_id":365}]},{"parent_id":66,"children":[{"child_id":365},{"child_id":366},{"child_id":367}]}]}

const resultArray = data.parents.reduce((arr, parent) => {
  return arr.concat(parent.children.map(child => ({
    grandparent_id: data.grandparent_id,
    parent_id: parent.parent_id,
    child_id: child.child_id
  })))
}, [])

console.info('resultArray =', resultArray)
```

Comment: How can we convert this into an object of arrays?

Comment: How can we convert this into an object of arrays?                                               [{grandparent_id:'7',parent_id:'65',child_id:'365'},{grandparent_id:'7',parent_id:'66',child_id:'365'},{grandparent_id:'7',parent_id:'66',child_id:'366'},{grandparent_id:'7',parent_id:'66',child_id:'367'}]

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Will this work if there are more deeper levels? Like let's say children array had another nested array.

Comment: @user4101343 no, it's not recursive

Comment: Can you help me with a recursive function please?

Comment: @user4101343 I suggest you ask it in a new question